# Search and match data from two files in Python

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, append

I have two different files; A reference file and a data sets with different length.

```
A reference file ("location.dat") contains:
40505   5.0666667   102.2166667
40517   5.6833333   101.8500000
40586   5.7666667   102.2000000
40587   5.8166667   102.0500000
40663   6.0333333   102.1166667
41525   5.5500000   100.4833333
41529   5.3500000   100.4000000 
...............
...............

A data sets ("input.dat") contains:
40517   2014    12  18  0   17.4
40586   2014    12  18  0   9.9
40587   2014    12  18  0   15.5
40663   2014    12  18  0   30.9
41525   2014    12  18  0   0
41529   2014    12  18  0   0
41540   2014    12  18  0   0
41543   2014    12  18  0   0
41548   2014    12  18  0   0
41549   2014    12  18  0   0
41551   2014    12  18  0   0
41610   2014    12  18  0   0
```

Question:
How to search and match data set so that the output file will combine certain selected values from both files like this:

```
output.dat
40517   5.6833333   101.8500000 17.4
40586   5.7666667   102.2000000 9.9
40587   5.8166667   102.0500000 15.5
............
...........

The current script is:

data1=np.loadtxt('location.dat')
   lats1=data1[:,1]
   lons1=data1[:,2]
   code1=data1[:,0]

    data2=np.loadtxt('input.dat')
    rain=data2[:,5]
    code2=data2[:,0]

    ind=[]
    for i in range(len(data1)):
       dist=code1[i]
       ind.append(np.where(dist==np.int(dist))[0][0])
       rain2=rain[ind]

    data3=np.array([code1,lats1,lons1,rain2])
    data3=np.transpose(data3)
    np.savetxt('output.dat',data3,fmt='%9.3f')
```

The current result

```
40517.000     5.683   101.850     0.000
40586.000     5.767   102.200     0.000
40587.000     5.817   102.050     0.000
40663.000     6.033   102.117     0.000
41525.000     5.550   100.483     0.000
41529.000     5.350   100.400     0.000
41540.000     5.383   100.550     0.000
```

The rain2 values did not properly append from the input file. How to convert the first column output to be integer?.Any ideas of what went wrong??.TQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
ind.append(np.where(dist==np.int(dist))[0][0])
```

does not make sense in your code. This will always append 0 if `dist`is an integer (as `dist==np.int(dist)` is simply the array [True])

A better way to solve your problem is to create a look-up table from the data in `location.dat`

```
data1=np.loadtxt('location.dat')
lookup = {int(round(id_)):(lat,long) for id_, lat, long in data1}
```

Please note that the best way to convert a float to an int in python is to use `int(round(i))`

You can then iterate over the data in your other file and create the proper line

```
data3 = []
for line in data2:
    ind = int(round(line[0]))
    data3.append([ind, lookup[ind][0], lookup[ind][1], line[5]])
```

To save the data, you may want to format and write the line one after the other or use `savetxt`.

Comment: wow!...awesome...thanks a lot...managed to save the output properly without hectic